# How to get to Soltheim on Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have seen many explinations saying "go to a city and finish dragons rising" problem is that I had already completed dragons rising before I downloaded the DLC. How do I fix this. (There is no boat at the Windhelm docks)

Answer (score 4):

It wasn't clear whether you have been attacked by cultists yet - if not just wait until you are attacked by cultists - in the next town you enter. That attack (which is easily defeated) will result in you coming in possesion of a note - and the existence of the ship at windhelm.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to get to Soltheim:

1. When you get attacked by Cultists, kill them then loot them. This will also start a new quest called "Dragonborn".
2. One of the cultists will have a letter, read it then you will get a new objective. The letter will also tell you where to go and how to get to Soltheim.